# Problem with adding firebase crashlytics android

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have added this lines to project level gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.1'
```

then these lines at app gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

and these lines as well

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:<version>'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:<version>'
```

and I received an error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:17:5-64:19 to override.
```

then I tried to fix this error by adding this line to manifest:

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

but this line didn't help me. Maybe someone knows how to add firebase crashlytics support to my android app? Where I made an error?

Comment: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

Add this line and remove all line related to the appcompact dependence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is happening because `crashlytics` already migrated to AndroidX but your app is still using Support Library.

You can find more info about how to migrate to android X here:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: so I have to migrate to androidx?

Comment: I think it is the best solution. It is simple, in the end. It will convert all "suport.something" imports to "androidx.something". Another option is use an old version of crashlytics (before they migrate to AndroidX)

Comment: @W0rmH0le can you tell me in which version of crashlytics they migrated to AndroidX? I am looking for same but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using the new Material library with the legacy Support Library. You have to migrate android.support to androidx in order to use com.google.android.material.

add below line in gradle file and try

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```